# CSS - Print: repeat background through all the page

Tags: css, printing, background

I have the following problem:

When I print a certain page from my website, and the content of this page doesn't fill all the paper, the background image cuts there. But what I need is to have the background image repeated through all the paper, no matter how much of the paper is taken by the contents.

I'm so sorry, I know it's a little odd this question, so I had a lot of trouble trying to explain it.

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use this..:

```
    body
{
    background-color:#454545;
background-image:url("background.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: contain;
    zoom: 100%;
}
```

paste this in your css, it is "attachment fixed" that you are looking for...the background image will never scroll with rest of the page and also you can apply "fixed" to other elements to make them scroll-free.

Answer (score 0):

If the background is attached to the BODY element and it is set to `background-repeat: norepeat` in your CSS, try

```
@page {
  margin: 1cm; /* or any other small value, maybe even 0 */
}

@media print {
  body {
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but the problem remains. Let's say the content takes one and a half sheet of paper. In the first one ok the background repeats through all the page, but in the second it still just goes until the half.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your image is right in the body tag, your only chance is setting

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../bg.png) repeat 0 0;
}
```

But you will never be able to have the background stretch all over the paper as the browser sets a margin on every border. This can be set to 0 by the user in the printing dialog, but can't be controlled by the css / you.

Comment: Thanks a lot but the problem remains. Let's say the content takes one and a half sheet of paper. In the first one ok the background repeats through all the page, but in the second it still just goes until the half.